# How can I make basic auto save program?

Tags: windows-10

I do a robotics club and the IDE that is used doesn't have autosave built-in. So how can I make basic auto save program in Windows 10 by Virtually typing Control+S every 15 Min?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome.

You can install [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and then find some persistent script on the Web, like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Morrowind/comments/a46y7a/autohotkey_script_for_timed_autosave_morrowind/).

Comment: It might be worth expanding this answer with some example code in case that link ever dies.